# Azure Synapse Workspace failed to load ressources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

We have different resources (storage account, logic app, SQL database, SQL server, Synapse Workspace) under a directory and a subscription (let's call them directory_1 and subscription_1)

The resources are used to perform simple ETL pipelines.

We want to move all these resources to a new directory and subscription (directory_2, subscription_2), everything moves correctly except the Synapse Worksapce.

When we try to access it shows this error:

Failed to load one or more resources due to no access, error code 403.

- Pipeline
- Related service
- Trigger
- Data flow
- Dataset
- Credentials
- SQL script
- Spark job definition
- Synapse KQL Scripts
- Notebook
- Lake databases

Both accounts (from directory_1 and Directory_2) have [Owner] and [Contributor] roles for the Azure Synapse Workspace and the resources group as well.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Unfortunately, you cannot transfer an entire Azure Synapse Analytics workspace to another subscription.**

Before moving Azure resources to another **Subscription**, check whether the resource type supports ***move operation*** or not by checking this **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftsynapse)**

[image]

According to this, **Microsoft** won’t support move operation of **Azure Synapse workspace** to another resource group or **subscription** or region.

This may be the reason behind getting that error.

I recommend you to upvote the request submitted by another Azure customer in the below forum.

[Transfer an entire Azure Synapse Analytics workspace to another subscription · Community](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9003ecc0-0b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)

**Reference:**

[Transfer an entire Azure Synapse Analytics workspace to another subscription - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/127299/transfer-an-entire-azure-synapse-analytics-workspa.html)